# Detect Debug Mode in Managed C++

Tags: .net, c++, .net-2.0

What's the best way to detect whether an app is running in debug mode in Managed C++/C++/CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array<Object^>^ debuggableAttributes = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->GetCustomAttributes(DebuggableAttribute::typeid, false);

Console::WriteLine(debuggableAttributes->Length > 0);
```

(The compiler adds a DebuggableAttribute to an assembly when compiled in debug mode)

Answer (score 5):

[IsDebuggerPresent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345(VS.85).aspx)?

Or if it's built with debug? For regular C++ it's easy (_DEBUG is defined), for managed I don't know.